# Python string comparison giving unexpected output

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to compare two variables:

`node_latest_version` - comes from scraping 
`installed_version` - by executing `node -v` and storing the value on a variable.

**On execute show the same value :**

```
print(node_latest_version)
# prints v11.13.0

print(installed_version)
# prints v11.13.0
```

But when I try to compare both

```
if node_latest_version == installed_version:
    print('success')
# No response
```

I've tried:

```
if node_latest_version == 'v11.13.0':
   print('OK')
# this prints OK

if installed_version == 'v11.13.0':
   print('OK')
# NO RESPONSE
```

Also

```
if type(node_latest_version) == str:
   print('OK')
# this prints OK

if type(installed_version) == str:
   print('OK')
# this prints OK
```

This is my code:

```
node_latest_version = results[1].attrs['data-version']

installed_version = subprocess.Popen("node -v",
                           shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0]

print(node_latest_version)
print(installed_version)

if node_latest_version == installed_version:
   print('OK')
```

I was hoping to compare both values

Comment: How do you get `results`? Also, try doing `print(repr(node_latest_version))` and `print(repr(installed_version))` and that might show you that they have some different characters

Comment: I suspect that one of them contains a newline character and the other does not.

Comment: Be careful with printing strings, that will *not* make it easy for you to notice what special characters might be in the string. Use `print(repr(...))` instead, so you can see if there are newlines or trailing spaces or other not-so-easily spotted characters in the values.

Comment: `results` come from scraping, by doing `print(repr())` i can see a difference now, `print(repr(node_latest_version))` shows `'v11.13.0'` and `print(repr(installed_version))` shows `'v11.13.0\n'`

Comment: And a quick test: `$ python3 -c 'import subprocess; r = subprocess.run("node -v", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True); print(repr(r.stdout))'` produces
`'v11.13.0\n'`. That `\n` there is a newline, something that is not so easy to spot when you print it out and check how many empty lines there are before the next item being printed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .strip() method on both the strings before comparison.
installed.strip() == latest.strip()

Answer (score -1):

Try this and compare:

```
node_latest_version = ''.join(x for x in node_latest_version if x.isdigit() or x == '.')
installed_version = ''.join(x for x in installed_version if x.isdigit() or x == '.')

if node_latest_version == installed_version:
   print('OK')
```

Comment: That is unnecessarily complicated and gives false positives e.g. if one is `11.2` and the other is `1.12` or `1.1.2`.

Comment: The only way to compare the two is by removing the extra characters.  So either you will use regex (even more complicated) or some other filter.  You can add `or x == '.' if you need to.